# Xcode 5 codesign wants to sign using key "<key>"

Tags: ios, xcode

I was archiving my app for the first time using Xcode 5 and I got the following prompt :-

```
codesign wants to sign using key "<key>"
```

I proceeded to Allow it and after asking the same thing one more time, it archived the app. I clicked on the estimated size (in App Store) and it showed 702 KB (very small size so not sure if it is correct) . I checked the following link :-

[Xcode > Product > Archive, codesign issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491329/xcode-product-archive-codesign-issue)

and it suggested that the above issue is fine. However, when I looked at the following link :-

[xcode 4.2, code signing for distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797979/xcode-4-2-code-signing-for-distribution)

it suggested that provisioning profiles and certificates need to be deleted (although the size of the archive is mentioned as 0 and it is xcode 4.2).

So, has anybody else faced this kind of issue ?